# DB2 SQL Select All With Columns As

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am working with some SQL queries on DB2. Is it possible to select all the columns in a table and also specify certain conditions using the "as" keyword within that select statement? For example, is this query possible:

```
select
  *,
  col1 + col2 as sum1,
  col3 - col4 as dif1
from 
  table;
```

Whenever I attempt this, I am getting the SQL0104 error and it is saying "Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: FROM INTO".

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
This query is running inside an SQLRPGLE program on an AS400.

Comment: Yes it is possible, at least with current versions of Db2-LUW. As you have obfuscated your query , no further advice is possible unless you give facts about your environment (versions, platforms) and the actual query.

Comment: ....yeesssss, but you generally don't want to, at least at the outermost level: If the underlying table changes it can cause programs to randomly break, since the data-structure used on the program side (especially if RPGLE!) will most likely not have been updated.  Doing `SELECT *` can have other performance issues as well, since you may be selecting columns that could be otherwise eliminated from the query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your table alias in front of the *.  So:

```
select
  t.*,
  col1 + col2 as sum1,
  col3 - col4 as dif1
from 
  table t;
```

Comment: Or, if you don't like table aliases, use the table name: `select table.*, ...`